# underscoreGS groupBy array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, underscore.js

I'am trying underscoreGS to group array

```
function myFunction() {
var arrays = [1.1, 1.3,2.7];
  Logger.log(underscoreGS._groupBy(arrays, function(num){return Math.floor(num);}));
}
```

and getting an error - **ReferenceError: Object "each" is undefined**.

Tried many ways to write iterator function, but same result. What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you importing that library?

Comment: I am importing the library by key: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/underscoregs. And it's working but not when I try to use _groupBy.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a new version on github - see https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/dist/Underscore.gs. I tried it and groupby seems to work.